# Character modelling for rigging

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify

I do not know if this is the right place to ask but I will give it a shot.

I'm creating a game character and i'm stuck at the rigging. I´ve tried different ways to rig the character. Rigify worked but I couldn´t import it to Unity and found no answers on how to fix it. After that I tried to create my own rig but after weight painting the character I noticed that vertices with 0 weight still moved when I moved the bone.

Now i'm thinking that there is something weird with the mesh and want to create a new character but I dont want it to have the same problems. So, the question is: how do I create a model which is riggable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately that is a question that is too general for this stack exchange.  I suggest changing your question to one specifically about what goes wrong when you tried to import the rigify version of the rig into Unity.  Perhaps you could get an answer to that specifically?

Comment: This video goes through the full process https://youtu.be/f-mx-Jfx9lA, but stack exchange is meant to answer more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows how to import Rigify animations to Unity:

[Animation import into Unity - mesh deform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170561/animation-import-into-unity-mesh-deform/170562#170562)

If a vertex moves after moving a bone, it has some weights: maybe you read 0 but instead it's 0.002, maybe it has 0 weight relatively for its bone (i.e. the forearm) but it has some weight relatively to any children bone (i.e. the hand).

In edit mode you can select the moving vertex and read all its weights assignements in the "N" properties panel, vertex weights tab.